# Concatenate mysqldumps in bash process substitution?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have two databases which I need to dump with a different dump settings. Usually I dump them to a file first, then concatenate them and send via ssh where required.

I wonder if the following approach would also work, or would it just jam my memory, as server has less RAM than the size of the dumps.

```
# cat <(mysqldump ${OPTIONS_1}) <(mysqldump ${OPTIONS_2}) | ssh host mysql
```

or

```
# cat <(mysqldump ${OPTIONS_1}) <(mysqldump ${OPTIONS_2}) > >(ssh host mysql)
```

`Bash` man page has a warning:

> When available, process substitution is performed simultaneously...

So I assume it would try to read full dumps in parallel to the memory first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process substitution is essentially just syntactic sugar around writing to a pipe. Each `mysqldump` can only write so much to a relatively small buffer before it blocks until `cat` reads some data from the buffer.

However, a simpler solution is to just use a command group to combine the two dumps; there is no sense running the dumps in parallel if `cat` isn't reading from the second one until the first one is done.

```
{ mysqldump ${OPTIONS_1}; mysqldump ${OPTIONS_2}; } | ssh host mysql
```